# Need to combine Splunk queries by feeding the results of one to the other

Tags: splunk

We are having to search through hundreds of alerts on a daily basis to test a new fraud system.  The problem is we have to review every alert which is very time consuming.

The 1st query gets the list of alerts and the details for each.

The 2nd query takes the used ID, and search for 3 specific events which can be 0 to many.
If the are no records, then add "NULL" to user ID, "N" to the device ID, and $0.00 to the amount

The results of both queries need to be put into a table for extract.

```
index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event EventTypeID=1095 
| dedup OLBUserID
| table _time, SessionID, EventTypeID, OLBUserID, score, risk_rating, reason_code 
| sort _time
```

```
index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event EventTypeID=1000 OR EventTypeID=1011 OR EventTypeID=1012 OLBUserID=<Results from 1st query>
| table UDID, Amount
```

If there are no results in the second query for the User ID, then make "UDID"="N", and "Amount"=$0.00

```
``

Table layout of results of combined query:
--_time = Date\Timestamp (1st Query)
--SessionID = "SessionID" (1st Query)
--OLBUserID = "UserID" (1st Query)
--Deposit? = ("Y" or "N") (2nd Query)
--score = "Score" (1st Query)
--risk_rating = "Rating" (1st Query)
--reason_code = "Reason Code"  (1st Query)
```

Comment: I have also tried the join command

index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event EventTypeID=1095 
| dedup OLBUserID 
| join type=left SessionID
    [ search index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event EventTypeID=1000 OR EventTypeID=1011 OR EventTypeID=1012] 
| eval "Deposit?"=case(Amount<=0.0000, "N", Amount>0.0000, "Y") 
| table _time, SessionID, UDID, EventTypeID, OLBUserID, "Deposit?", score, risk_rating, reason_code 
| sort _time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually had to change the way the search works.  First you have to search for all items that have "EventTypeID=1095" only.  Then take those results, and add them to the sub-search.  I added blank fields so the users could export it directly to a spreadsheet to do there research.

Final SPL:

```
index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event EventTypeID=1095
| dedup OLBUserID 
| join type=left SessionID 
    [ search index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event EventTypeID=1000 OR EventTypeID=1011 OR EventTypeID=1012]
| eval "Deposit?"=case(Amount<=0.0000, "N", Amount>0.0000, "Y") 
| table _time, SessionID, UDID, OLBUserID, "Deposit?", Amount, "Bank#", "Acct Type", "Acct#", "Fraud?", "Comments", score, risk_rating, reason_code 
| sort -_time
```

Answer (score 0):

"" immediately brings to mind a subsearch, but that won't work in this case because the subsearch returns too many fields.

Try combining the two searches using `stats`.  Something like this:

```
index=mbank_p_database sourcetype=mbank_event (EventTypeID=1095 OR EventTypeID=1000 OR EventTypeID=1011 OR EventTypeID=1012) 
| stats values(*) as * by OLBUserID
| table _time, SessionID, EventTypeID, OLBUserID, score, risk_rating, reason_code
```